# iOS static vs dynamic framework 4

Tags: ios, frameworks, lib

There are previous threads about iOS static vs dynamic framework. However, I still need to clarification on this one. What my understanding is:

1. There are static and dynamic framework in iOS.
2. Static framework is essentially a package of static lib (.a) and other resources like bundle and header files.
3. Only Apple can create dynamic framework in iOS.
4. Regular developer outside Apple can only create static framework.

Is my understanding, correct?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not.

3.- Anyone can create dynamic frameworks on iOS.
4.- Any developer can create Static libraries, static frameworks or dynamic frameworks.